# Memory leak when deploying jboss

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, memory-leaks, wildfly, heap-memory

Wildfly 8.2.0

We have issue a were something is taking up to much memory in our wildflys after deploying.

We have two wildflys behind an apache, we put some load on the wildflys and start a deploy. We do not restart the wildflys after deplying, we only reload the wildfly.

I took a heapdump and I can se that there is duplicate of this object: org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.

How we reproduced the issue:
First deploy and everything looked fine.

Second deploy and we saw two org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl 
object.

Third deploy and we saw 3 org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.

So for every deploy we made we saw that a new instance of org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl was created and the old ones were not removed.

This is obviously not good and I can't understand why the objects aren't removed and what they do.

[image: after thrid deploy]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtEO3.jpg

Do anyone have a ide of what the problem can be ?

Comment: How are you deploying the application?

Comment: We are doing a cli deployment and deploy a ear package

Comment: That doesn't seem unreasonable to me. Having a class created each time you deploy is pretty common. Maybe you need to tweak your GC settings.